# Webpack Encore and import React

Tags: reactjs, symfony, webpack, import, webpack-encore

I am trying a React project with Symfony and Webpack Encore.

I have added the following packages :

```
yarn add @babel/preset-react --dev
yarn add --dev react react-dom
```

For this, I had to add `import React from 'react'` on every .jsx files and it worked.
However, I was wondering if there is not a smarter way to do so instead of repeating the import every time

I found and tried different approaches, and installed `yarn add --dev @babel/core @babel/preset-env babel-loader` too but without any luck. Apparently, the fact that Encore is used seems to complexify things more than simplifying

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for Webpack Encore after reading this [article](https://www.reactjunkie.com/automatically-import-react) and this [one](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/custom-loaders-plugins.html) and this [one](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/)

In webpack.config.js I added this

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

Encore
    // ...
    .addPlugin(new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            React: "react" // automatically import react where needed
    }))
```

It works just fine but still not sur it is the smartest solution